# MythTV 0.28 on Mint 19/Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mythbuntu, mythtv

I'd like to install **v0.28** of MythTV-Frontend onto a new Ubuntu 18.04 box rather than the bionic repo's **v0.29**.

This machine is a remote frontend to my HTPC which is running MythTV 0.28 (on Ubuntu 16.04) and I don't want to update that at this time.

There is a mythbuntu ppa but it suggest it only runs on 'artful' and earlier systems - is it worth playing with this?

Comment: Mint is not an official Ubuntu flavor, so is off-topic here. If you want to ask about Ubuntu *and* Mint, please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead, otherwise please [edit] your question to focus on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not update the HTPC to use version 29 via PPA? http://www.mythbuntu.org/repos

Comment: Oh, maybe because of this: https://askubuntu.com/q/944270/21005

Comment: Hi Jarno. I'm still scarred by my experience upgrading from 0.27 to 0.28 which ended with a complete new build of 0.28.  I love MythTV, but it's a common comment - _when its working leave it alone!_  The 0.28 primary frontend/backend is really stable and needs virtually no maintenance, so I don't want to touch it.  I just want to update a secondary frontend to Ubuntu 18.04 (as it's used for other things as well) but still run 0.28 frontend on it.